# Print values side by side

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am trying to output the values side by side. I have pasted the example and code of what I am trying to accomplish. Is this possible?

```
import requests
import json

r = requests.get('https://api.website.com',headers = {"content-type": "application/json", "X-Auth-Key":"key-here","X-Auth-Email":"email@"})

#packages_json = r.json()
#packages_list = json.dumps(packages_json, indent=2)



with open("C:\\Users\\vm\\Desktop\\newjson.json") as access_json:
#   print(packages_list, file = access_json)
#   data = pd.read_json(access_json)
#   print(data)
    read_content = json.load(access_json)
#print(read_content)


#for i in range(0,len(read_content['result']['totals'])):

unique = read_content['result']['totals']['uniques']['all']
requests = read_content['result']['totals']['requests']['all']
print("Unique Visitors " + str(unique))
print("Total Requests " + str(requests))
```

what I want it to look like:

```
Unique Visitors 862 next-value1 next-value2 next-value3

Total Requests 2866 next-value1 next-value2 next-value3
```

Basically, it's reading the value from the json file which is fetching the data from the API on an hourly basis. What I am trying to accomplish is that the script run every hour and look into the file and fetch whatever the current value place it next to the existing value.

Answer (score 0):

If the `unique` variable is a list you could do:

```
print("Unique Visitors " + '   '.join(unique))
```

But you'll be better off using the logging module so it will go to a specific log file in the format you want.